# Days between two dates in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two columns in my list called start date and end date. I just want the difference of days between those two dates. I want to add column that having number of difference between two days. so what should be the formula for that calculated column. I strongly need that help asap.thanks in advance. Please help.

Comment: i dont have that much reputations. sorry

Comment: You can always accept answers to your questions. Just click on the 'check' sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following formula:

```
=DATEDIF([StartDateColumn], [EndDateColumn],"d")
```